# Get first occurence of match before a positive lookahead with single line flag modifier

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My regex

`(\d*,\d*) \d*/\d*(?=.*?Open Recall Check)`

matches on everything of interest except it matches on too much... I would like to only return the first mileage match directly prior to "Open Recall Check". Instead it matches on all mileages.

[In my example at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RzSsLf/2), I get 29 matches but of those, I'm only trying to return these 10:

- 75,115 (corresponds with match 1)
- 92,748 (corresponds with match 7)
- 62,300 (corresponds with match 8)
- 55,113 (corresponds with match 9)
- 109,308 (corresponds with match 11)
- 138,131 (corresponds with match 17)
- 125,197 (corresponds with match 24)
- 55,335 (corresponds with match 25)
- 69,100 (corresponds with match 28)
- 6,010 (corresponds with match 29)

One way I though I could do this was to return all matches in a list and then just filter any that show up before the phrase "Open Recall Check", but I haven't been able to figure out how to include that phrase in the list 10 times (every regex variation I've tried also inludes it 29 times... so not very helpful).

What can I tweak to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not match all the other odometer readings prior to an `Open Recall Check`, in your lookahead to match `Open Recall Check`, for each character you have to assert that at that point you don't match another odometer reading. You can do this with a negative lookahead within the positive lookahead:

```
(?=(?:.(?!(?:\d+,)?\d+ \d+/\d+))*?Open Recall Check)
```

Note that one of your odometer readings is just `5`, so you need to make the digits and comma before it optional to allow for that i.e.

```
((?:\d+,)?\d+)
```

Also, for better regex performance, it is better to make the `\d*` into `\d+`. Overall, that gives this regex:

```
((?:\d+,)?\d+) \d+/\d+(?=(?:.(?!(?:\d+,)?\d+ \d+/\d+))*?Open Recall Check)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Sr5ZXH/1)

Note that based on the data you have put on regex101, match 5 should actually be `5`, not `109,308`.

Comment: Nick, you're a wizard!!! And thank you for the performance recommendations :)